# Generated proto files not found in docker container, but found in local machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, python-poetry, proto

My docker container's file structure is the following [File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRbAA.png)

Below is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install poetry

ADD ../services/ingest/ ./services/ingest/
ADD ../protos/datapipeline/ ./protos/datapipeline/

WORKDIR /app/services/ingest
RUN poetry install

CMD [ "poetry", "run", "python", "ingest/processor.py"]
```

I copied the services/ingest and protos/datapipeline folders in such a way that they should be in the same level as in my local machine.

The project also uses poetry with the following line for accessing the python proto files within the pyproject.toml located in the services/ingest folder

```
datapipeline = {path = "../../protos/datapipeline"}
```

the container should then go to /app/services/ingest and launch services/ingest/ingest/processor.py using the poetry enviroment which has datapipeline.datapipeline as a module. But running it this way the program cannot locate it even though it works outside the container and produces the following error.

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'datapipeline.datapipeline'
  File "/app/services/ingest/ingest/processor.py", line 9, in <module>
    import datapipeline.ingest
```

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated on getting this working.

File is imported the following way in processor.py

```
import datapipeline.ingest
```

Comment: Be careful with the Docker context. It's the file structure root on the (often) `.` used in the `docker build` command e.g. `docker build --tag=.... --file=./Dockerfile .`. Only directories that fall under the context may be `ADD`'ed and `COPY`'ed. Using `ADD ../something` is outside of the context and so likely fails. You should set the context so that everything you need to `ADD` and `COPY` falls under its root.

Comment: It's more common to use `COPY` instead of `ADD` though this shouldn't affect the observed behavior.

Comment: I should mention this is the docker build command I used, `sudo docker build -t ingest -f docker/Dockerfile.ingest . ` I can confirm the `ADD` command added the correct files to the container but for some reason when running the program it does not see them.